# Spanish writing website?

Tags: websites

I am looking for a website that is community based for reviews in spanish.

Does someone know anything?

The website is to publish stories, narrative, novels, poems and such, that would be reviewed by a community. Or something of the sort.

For example I know that in english the is www.thenextbigwriter.com but that's it. Not much in spanish to be honest!! (That I can find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some websites where you can publish your short stories and novels in Spanish :

1) http://www.e-stories.org/categories.php?&lan=es&art=s

2) http://megustaescribir.com/

3) http://www.everywritersresource.com/

Comment: NO no I am NOT looking for a spanish Q&A website. I am looking for a writer's website!

Comment: means you want a writer's website where you can write comments or reviews in spanish. Am I right?

Comment: What I mean is I want to publish my writing (Short stories, novels, etc...) and get reviews, and also to review the works of other users. Much like thenextbigwriter.com etc... But in Spanish of course.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope these websites will serve your purpose.

Comment: @Joze - So you want a place on the web to publish stories? I didn't get that from your question. Can you please edit the question to reflect this? Thanks!

Comment: @Neil Fein, Joze has provided the link in the question thenextbigwriter.com and has specified that he wants one such website in spanish. However, still at first I was also confused with the question. It's good if he makes it more simple to understand.

Comment: I edited it to make it clear. Thanks for the website. I think only megustaescribir.com qualifies. But that works for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There is a new website called Nubyee that has a version in [English](https://www.nubyee.com) and [Spanish](https://www.nubyee.com/es/). It's not exactly a page where you get reviews but people can comment and like your stories. The only condition to publish is that they have to be true stories. I hope it helps.